# Counting values comma separated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

```
A   V
-   -
A1  B, C
A2  C, 2W
A3  D
A4  10K, 10W, 2A
```

I would like to count the values in V and order them by occurrence. Expected output:

```
O  COUNT(*)
-  -------
W       12
K       10
A        2
C        2
B        1
D        1
```

Comment: Do you care about column A?

Comment: How in the world did a data model this atrocious come into existence?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of problems.

Comment: @FrankChen not really

Comment: @JustinCave given table, nothing I can do :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of `REGEX_SUBSTR()` and `REGEXP_REPLACE()` functions along with hierarchical query assuming all comma-seperated elements, whenever white spaces are trimmed, are of the form ***a positive integer + a letter*** such as

```
WITH t2 AS
(
 SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(v,'[^,]+',1,level)) AS v
   FROM t 
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(v,',')+1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR a = a
)
SELECT NVL(SUM(REGEXP_REPLACE(v,'[^[:digit:]]')),
           CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>1 THEN COUNT(*) END)||REGEXP_REPLACE(v,'[^[:alpha:]]') AS o
  FROM t2 
 GROUP BY REGEXP_REPLACE(v,'[^[:alpha:]]')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=20e0c7cb9f9f4f94fbdae2a1fc3141f1)</kbd>

**Edit** (depending on the last edit of the question) : just remove conctenation operator, and conditional for `COUNT` aggregation such as

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(v,'[^[:alpha:]]') AS o,
       NVL(SUM(REGEXP_REPLACE(v,'[^[:digit:]]')),COUNT(*)) AS count 
  FROM t2 
 GROUP BY REGEXP_REPLACE(v,'[^[:alpha:]]') 
 ORDER BY count DESC, o
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=94d224d91e1629190932e1b0710802c9)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, I've just realised I mistyped the expected output. Could the answer be tweaked to produce the new output?